# How to properly build an optimize Angular 5 Project?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular5

I'm new to Angular 5 project. I ran `ng build --prod` to generate a `dist/` folder.

I noticed it takes quite a long time to build, and when I opened up my `dist/` folder, I saw it has almost 98% useless stuff in there, like SVGs, images, and so on ..

How do I control what goes into my `dist/` ?

---

**.angular-cli.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "web"
  },
  "apps": [{
    "root": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "assets": [
      "assets",
      "favicon.ico"
    ],
    "index": "index.html",
    "main": "main.ts",
    "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
    "test": "test.ts",
    "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
    "prefix": "app",
    "styles": [
      "styles.css",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
      "../src/assets/css/style.css",
      "../src/assets/css/colors/blue.css"

    ],
    "scripts": [
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "../node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
      "../node_modules/pace-js/pace.min.js"
    ],
    "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
    "environments": {
      "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
      "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  }],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [{
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

---

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 4202",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "3.2.16",
    "angular2-image-upload": "^1.0.0-rc.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
    "ngx-toastr": "8.0.0",
    "ngx-uploader": "4.2.1",
    "pace-js": "1.0.2",
    "popper.js": "1.13.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.0",
    "sticky-kit": "1.1.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

---

How do I **optimize** it? And only build what require for my site?

Currently, it takes **15** minutes to build on my server. How do I make it build faster?

Comment: What do you mean with 'useless stuff'? Also what do you mean with optimize? Faster? Smaller? Both? If so, what is your current performance?

Comment: 15 min is too much. Can you give some more details on the total size of dist dir? I don't see any useless things in my prod build and it only got images that I use in the project and nothing is useless for me and takes 75 seconds. Also, it would be great if you share the screen once the build finished.

Answer (score 15):

For the build being slow you can use this version of the angular cli:

`"@angular/cli": "1.7.0-beta.0",`

this cut my building time from 30 minutes to 3 minutes.

In Angular 5, AOT and build-optimizer are by default in prod builds.

`ng build --prod --named-chunks` adding --named-chunks to your build command will give you named chunks so you can better analyze you chunks, and better enhance what you are importing in each module.
An example that maybe you are importing the whole shared module into a certain module while you just use one thing from that shared module

Comment: Wow, I can wait to try your suggestion. Is there any down side ?

Comment: No, Not really!! the angular team is doing their best to reduce the build time.
The only thing I noticed so far is that build chunk sizes increased a little bit, nothing to worry about it I guess.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6795#issuecomment-361083966

Comment: After adding that to my `package.json` I seems to get this error all the time `Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'`

Comment: npm -v
5.6.0
/ node -v
v8.9.4

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions >

Comment: @ihue try the solution here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9307.
just make sure you use the version 1.7.0-beta.0

Answer (score 6):

You need to take a moment to analyze your dependencies and the impact they are having on your builds dist output.

Build with:

```
ng build --target=production --environment=prod --aot --build-optimizer -sourcemaps --stats-json
```

(Though some of these arguments are implied, I chose verbosity in the event the environment has been modified beyond defaults.)

Which will output a `stats.json` file that can then be analyzed with `webpack-bundle-analyzer` by running: `webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json`

Remove unnecessary libraries, refactor for tree shaking, replace irresponsibly large libraries with alternatives.

Without seeing your package.json contents this should give you a starting point to begin understanding optimization for production.

References:

- angular cli build spec: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#bundling--tree-shaking
- Great write-up to get you started: https://yakovfain.com/2017/08/03/angular-cli-dev-and-prod-builds-with-jit-and-aot/

Comment: Thank-you. I upload my package.json, let me know, if you have other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the links you shared. I understand these more now. 
I already read this link : 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer

But still not sure, how to use `webpack-bundle-analyzer`

Answer (score 5):

A great tool I found was [source map explorer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer). It's a tool that shows to you space used for all imports you use in a module. The image is an example of my admin module when I run source map explorer:

[image]

This tool helped me a lot pointing me some imports that I forgot to remove and was letting my files too large.

Answer (score 2):

It's not junk, the ng build command by default will pick up the developer profile and will build the dist with all the required file on your project(ts get compiled to js for example). Because its a dev profile by default you see thing like the named .chunk file amongst other thing.Developer profile and prod profile also have different dependencies depending on your package.json file.

see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build for

Answer (score 2):

```
ng build --aot --prod --build-optimizer
```

Although aot and build optimizer are combined when using `ng build --prod`
so simply use `ng build --prod`

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to optimize the build for angular 5/6:

```
node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/.bin/ngbuild --aot --prod --build-optimizer
```

Comment: Can you format your command as code to make it more readable? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks Also having to change `max_old_space_size` on the node process seems a little odd. Can you elaborate more about how you decided that was necessary for your situation, why it might apply to other users, and how it helps improve build times? Adding `--aot` and `--build-optimizer` would make the build take even longer than the command in the original question.

Comment: `ng build --prod` already implicitly uses ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation so no need for `-aot`.

Answer (score 0):

you can run `brotli` compression after production build, which will improve the loading time.
https://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You can use node parameter `--max_old_space_size=5048`. But I prefer to setup it via environment:

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096
```

It speedup our build process on CI pipeline twice.

Answer (score -2):

```
config in angular.json

 "configurations": {
  "production": {
    "optimization": true,
    "outputHashing": "all",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "extractCss": true,
    "namedChunks": false,
    "aot":true,
    "extractLicenses": true,
    "vendorChunk": false,
    "buildOptimizer": false,
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ]
  }
}
and build your project :

 node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --build-optimizer=true --vendor-chunk=true --aot --base-href "/project/app"
```

Comment: It's Angular 5: there is no angular.json in Angular 5